# Network Error (tcp_error)

Tags: tcp, networking

When i browse my website that host on HostGator got following error.
Friends from other country said they can browse my site.
Is that ISP error?

```
Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message looks exactly like the default error messages of a Bluecoat proxy server. So most probably the proxy server that you use can't access the website. To determine a more specific reason you'll need to check (or have checked) the proxy logs.

Comment: +1 for defining the source of this error message as "Bluecoat".